# Facebook comments box plugin + dynamic url on asp?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, dynamic, comments

I'm trying to put the FB comments box on the bottom of each of my products pages on my site. I have managed to do this but when set to a static url it says the same comments on every product. I deleted the url and now it kind of works but says the plugin is in compatabilty mode.

Heres whats in my products template:

My site is trickscooter.co.uk so you can see. The comments box is at the bottom of every product.

I want people to be able to ask questions on the item shown so I can answer them so all can see.

PS - It says this:

Warning: this comments plugin is operating in compatibility mode, but has no posts yet. Consider specifying an explicit 'href' as suggested in the comments plugin documentation to take advantage of all plugin features.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The static URL won't do for the 'href' parameter as that parameter tells Facebook which comments to show. If you always use the same URL, of course you get always the same comments. You should have a unique url per product and use that dynamically.

If you generate the href parameter dynamically, you need to be aware that you will loose comments if your page is accessible under different domains.

The best way is to configure a 'facebook domain' (e.g. 'www.foo.example') and use that to generate your href attribute for Facebook comments.

If I misunderstood you please explain your current embedding code and what you tried. If you like the answer, please mark it as 'solution'.